# Angular service worker cache and non-deleting performance strategy

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

My app is designed to work offline, so I am using the freshness strategy. However, there are some areas that could be improved with caching while online.

I have specified that certain repeated calls to the API should use the performance strategy. This works except that *after an hour offline, those files disappear and the app stops working.*

**Is there a simple way to keep the performance strategy files available after their expiry**, so they can be still accessed offline? They may be old, but they will do when nothing else is available.

Its a catch 22 - I cannot optimise without losing the offline mode.

Basically, I want to have data less than an hour old when online, but offline I am happy with any data up to a week old.

My ngsw-config.json

```
"dataGroups": [
        {
            "name": "optimise",
            "urls": [
                "https://**/optimise.php"
            ],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "strategy": "performance",
                "maxSize" : 250,
                "maxAge"  : "1h"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "offline",
            "urls": [
                "https://**/offline.php"
            ],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "strategy": "freshness",
                "maxSize" : 250,
                "maxAge"  : "7d",
                "timeout" : "15s"
            }
        }
]
```